# Pythonic way to write for x in Y and not in Z

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I recently came across a seemingly simple situation, which I could not find a nice pythonic way to write. I wanted to ask SO for their solutions and which would be fastest.

I have two arrays, say `Arr1 = [-1, 0, 1, 2, 3]` and `Arr2 = [1, 2, 3]`. I want to get an array of the elements in Arr1 but not in Arr2. Again, super simple situation, but it turned out to be tricky to implement.

I tried variations of `[x in Arr1 and not Arr2]`, but because `not` evaluates to a Boolean this raises an error. I feel like python has a really nice and clean solution to this, but it is escaping my mind.

(My solution was `filter(lambda x: x not in Arr2, Arr1)`. It works, but it isn't a satisfying solution. Does SO have a more pythonic way?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The List Comprehension would look like this

```
>>> [item for item in Arr1 if item not in Arr2]
[-1, 0]
```

But, this is highly inefficient, as it has to do M * N iterations in the worst case, because the `in` operator will have to iterate through the elements of `Arr2` sequentially. So, better convert the `Arr2` to a set and then do it in the same way

```
>>> set2 = set(Arr2)
>>> [item for item in Arr1 if item not in set2]
[-1, 0]
```

Since we use a set here, which uses hashing to do the lookup, it would be faster than the linear list search approach.

If you have the liberty of converting both the lists to sets, *and the order of the elements in the result doesn't matter*, simply convert both the lists to sets and find the set difference, like this

```
>>> set1, set2 = set(Arr1), set(Arr2)
>>> set1 - set2
set([0, -1])
```

---

Just to show the impact of linear list searching in this list comprehension, just check this timing comparison.

```
>>> import random
>>> import timeit
>>> 
>>> def get_random_numbers(count=100):
>>>     return [random.randint(0, 10000) for _ in range(count)]
>>> 
>>> data1, data2 = get_random_numbers(10000), get_random_numbers(10000)
>>> set1, set2 = set(data1), set(data2)
>>> 
>>> timeit.timeit("[item for item in data1 if item not in data2]",
                    setup="from __main__ import data1, data2", number=100)
>>> 47.4242498875
>>> timeit.timeit("[item for item in data1 if item not in set2]",
                    setup="from __main__ import data1, set2", number=100)
>>> 0.0595960617065
>>> timeit.timeit("list(set1 - set2)",
                    setup="from __main__ import set1, set2", number=100)
>>> 0.033539056778
```

All the results are in seconds. See the magnitude of performance boost you get by using sets.

Comment: Why will the order change during set difference?

Comment: @andoni sets use hashing algorithm. The elements are not actually in the same order as we insert them.

Comment: @thefourtheye thank you. This was a really informative answer.

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> S = set(Arr2)
>>> [x for x in Arr1 if x not in S]
[-1, 0]
```

If the elements of `Arr2` are not hashable then just use it directly instead of generating a set from it. A set is preferred since containment testing on a set is approximately O(1), versus O(n) for a list.

Answer (score 3):

Python `list` does not support subtract operator, but `set` does. So,
transform your `lists` to `sets`, substract them and convert the result to a list.

```
Arr1 = [-1, 0, 1, 2, 3]
Arr2 = [1,2,3]
difference = list(set(Arr1) - set(Arr2))
print difference
>>[-1,0]
```

This approach is fasther than using compression list, because you need to check for each element in `Arr1` if is in `Arr2`, so is N*M.

Comment: What is the efficiency of list subtraction versus the above answers (converting to set and doing list-comprehension)?

Comment: @andonim it is also about order, this won't keep the order the elements appear in Arr1 if that is relevant

Comment: Don't forget `set(Arr1).difference(set(Arr2))` which does the same thing: "new set with elements in s but not in t" https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#set-objects

Comment: @andoni I'm not subtracting `lists`, they are sets, look at `set(Arr1)`

Comment: levi, my mistake. I get that now that you changed the code. It wasn't clear originally.

Comment: @BrentWashburne, if you are going to use set.difference you would not cast the second list as a set. It takes any iterable.